# Displaying variable label instead of variable name Stata's margins plot

Tags: stata

In `Stata`, I would like to run a regression and visually display each variable's coefficients and their confidence intervals relative to zero, as the code and figure shown below:

```
sysuse auto
regress price mpg weight length foreign gear_ratio headroom rep78
margins, dydx(*)
marginsplot, horizontal recast(scatter) xline(0, lcolor(red)) xscale(range()) yscale(reverse)
```

[image]

On the *y-axis*, I would like to display the **variable label** (on the right) instead of variable name. What kind of options can one use to make that configuration?

```
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
price           int     %8.0gc                Price
mpg             int     %8.0g                 Mileage (mpg)
weight          int     %8.0gc                Weight (lbs.)
length          int     %8.0g                 Length (in.)
foreign         byte    %8.0g      origin     Car type
gear_ratio      float   %6.2f                 Gear Ratio
headroom        float   %6.1f                 Headroom (in.)
rep78           int     %8.0g                 Repair Record 1978
```

I realize that this can be a basic question but any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way of instructing `marginsplot` to show the labels of a variable instead of its name. However, as @Skimwhistle has pointed out, you can use `ylabel` to manually get the desired output.

You can of course generalize this concept further by writing a small `r-class` program:

```
program define foo, rclass

syntax varlist

local i = 0

foreach var of local varlist {
    local ++i
    local varlabel : variable label `var'
    local varlabels `varlabels' `i' `" "`varlabel'" "'      
}

return local xvarlabels `varlabels'

end
```

Using this little program, which here we call `foo`, you can automatically obtain all variable labels in a `list` and then feed them to `marginsplot`:

```
clear
sysuse auto

local xvars mpg weight length foreign gear_ratio headroom rep78

foo `xvars'
local xvarlabels `r(xvarlabels)'

regress price `xvars'
margins, dydx(*)

marginsplot, horizontal allxlabels recast(scatter) xline(0, lcolor(red)) ///
xscale(range()) yscale(reverse) ylabel(`xvarlabels')
```

And voila, the labels are now all on the produced graph.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add:

ylabel(1 "Mileage (MPG)" 2 "Weight" *etc...* )

to the options of the marginsplot line.